# jquery : check each form with keyup in (for) function

Tags: jquery

i am using (for) to add multiple input form
i want to check this forms with keyup
but it always check the first form only

here is code

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $('input[name*="morein"]').keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var moreincheck = $("#moreincheck");
        if (value > 60) {
            moreincheck.css('display', 'block');
            moreincheck.text("error cant add more than 60");
        } else {
            moreincheck.css('display', 'none');
        }
    }).keyup();

    $("#divTxt").append('<inputname="morein[]"  type="text" />' + '<span id="moreincheck" class="checkerror"></span>');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs have to be **unique**! (and you noticed why). Furthermore you are re-adding the same event handler to all `input[name*="morein"]` in each iteration.

It is better to create the elements first, bind the event handler and use DOM traversal to find the corresponding element. For example:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   $('<input name="morein[]"  type="text" /><span class="checkerror"></span>').appendTo('#divTxt');
}

$('input[name*="morein"]').keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var moreincheck = $(this).next('span.checkerror');
    if (value > 60) {
        moreincheck.css('display', 'block');
        moreincheck.text("error cant add more than 60");
    } else {
        moreincheck.css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: first thank you for your reply 
but i tried your way and it failed :(

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise? What exactly "fails"? It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wbtha/. Type any number bigger than 60 into any box...

Answer (score 1):

**Make id unique**, or you could use class, and separate the event bind part out of the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $("#divTxt")
    .append('<input name="morein[]" type="text" class="morein" />')
    .append('<span class="checkerror"></span>');
}

// bind the event handler
$('input.morein').keyup(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var moreincheck = $this.next('.checkerror');
    // use .length to check the length
    if ($this.val().length > 60) {
        moreincheck.text("error cant add more than 60").show();
    } else {
        moreincheck.hide();
    }
});
```

***[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/T6hGp/)***

Comment: first thank you for your reply 
but i tried your way and it failed :(

Comment: @DragoN Check the demo i added, it should be working. Note, it check the length of the input, if you mean check with the number value 60, you should use `parseInt` etc.